# Firebug becoming unsusably slow with Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, firebug, performance-testing

I'm working on some simple Canvas demos and am running into problems with Firebug.  up until now, I've been doing my testing on Chrome and optimized the Canvas demo (Conway Game of Life in the background of the page) to about 20 FPS.  (I would like it to be faster but that's a matter for another question) 
  However, when testing in FF on the same machine, I get much worse performance - typically about 5-10 FPS.  Also, more disturbingly, it seems to slow over time, hinting at some sort of memory leak.

Unfortunately, when I try to use Firebug, the who browser grinds to a halt.  It remains responsive but incredibly slow.  I get about a frame per minute and button clicks often take 2-5 minutes to respond.  What is going on here?

Full code for the page is at: https://github.com/danheidel/resume-foundation

The page itself can be loaded here: http://danheidel.github.io/resume-foundation/#

Comment: I think the simple answer here is that Firebug adds a lot of overhead to JS code. It has to check for breakpoints, errors, log statements, and who knows what else and if you have JS executing many times a second that is going to degrade performance.

Comment: Yeah, I know that you're going to take a performance hit with a debugger but this is roughly a 500-fold drop in performance.  In Chrome I have no issues doing profiling and in Firebug on other pages, i see nothing even remotely approaching this level of slow-down.  I'm curious if there is a particular kind of function call that Firebug has it's hook in that is being hit particularly here.

Comment: Remember Firebug is javascript + DOM (anything it can do, you could do too through your own js)... its an amazing accomplishment, but the native inspectors have far surpassed it.

Answer (score 1):

Man, StackOverflow, you are disappoint lately...

Anyhow, I figured out that if you use the FF profiler through the Inspector menu (Cntl + Shift + I) instead of Firebug, it doesn't get all jammed up and works quite nicely.

Also, I was having some issues with the Chrome profiler giving inaccurate results because of too coarse time resolution.  If you open a tab with about:tracing, it will do an extremely fine-resolution trace on all open tabs.  (If you are profiling a Canvas app, like I am, don't forget to jump over to the tab you want to analyze since RequestAnimationFrame does not generally fire unless the tab is active and visible.)

Comment: Dan, firebug is implemented through Javascript. Use the native inspectors to get the performance your wanting. I honestly haven't used firebug in years now.